# Test class coverage for get method

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have give here some important code where I struck to make coverage.I struck in **SaveAssest()**  if condition under for loop. In **getparts()** partslist serial number is set as null but in visual force page we change that dynamically by calling that function and by changing its field but I can't able to do in test class.
If I call **getparts()** from test class partslist 2nd parameter is set as null so I can't able to cover that if condition in **SaveAssest()** which checks for not blank.How to resolve this.
Controller:

```
public class SitePartsUpdate{
public List<SiteParts> getParts(){
    if(flag){
    PartsList=new List<SiteParts>();
    for(SalesOrderLineItems__c OLI:SalesOLI){
        for(integer i=0;i<OLI.Quantity__c;i++){
            PartsList.add(new SiteParts(OLI.Product__r.Name,''));
        }
    }
    }

     system.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'+PartsList); 

    return PartsList;
}




public pagereference SaveAssest(){
    urlFlag= false;
    system.debug('====================================='+PartsList);
    SitePartsUpdate();
    flag=false;
    UpdateSN=new List<Inventory_Transaction__c>();
    RepeatSN=new Set<String>();

          for(SiteParts SNum :PartsList){



          if(!String.isBlank(SNum.serial)){
          system.debug('&&&&&&&&&&&&'+SNum.serial+'@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
          if(SN.containsKey(SNum.serial)){
          system.debug('>>>>>>>>>'+SN.get(SNum.serial).Product__c+'>>>>>>>>>'+SNum.productName+'>>>>>>>>>'+SN.get(SNum.serial).Name+'>>>>>>>>>'+SNum.serial);
          if(SN.get(SNum.serial).Product__c==SNum.productName && SN.get(SNum.serial).Name==SNum.serial){
          system.debug('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'+SNum.serial+'@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
          if(!RepeatSN.contains(SNum.serial)){
          system.debug('@@@@@@@@'+SNum.serial+'@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
          RepeatSN.add(SNum.serial);
          SN.get(SNum.serial).Transaction_Type__c='Delivered';
          SN.get(SNum.serial).SalesOrder__c=SalesId;
          if(SNum.selected){

              UpdateSN.add(SN.get(SNum.serial));
          } else {
              system.debug('SN ======'+SN.get(SNum.serial));
              unSelectedSN.add(SN.get(SNum.serial));
          }
          system.debug('$$$$$$$$$'+SNum.serial+'@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
          }else{ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Serial Number must be unique'));
                return null;
              }
          }else{ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Wrong Serial Number'));
                return null;
              }
          }
          else{ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Wrong Serial Number'));
                return null;
              }
          }else{ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Serial Number is mandatory'));
                return null;
              }


        }
       }


public class SiteParts{

    public String productName{get; set;}
    public String serial{get;set;}
    public Boolean selected{get;set;}

    public SiteParts(String Name, String SN){
      productName=Name;
      serial=SN;
    }
}
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="SitePartsUpdate" action="{!SitePartsUpdate}">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="MPbid">
<apex:pageblockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveAssest}" reRender="MPbid" />
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Parts}" var="prt" id="Pbid">
<apex:column headerValue="Log Asset">

<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!prt.selected}" />
</apex:column>



<apex:column headerValue="Product Name">
<apex:outputText >{!prt.productName}</apex:outputText>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Serial Number">
<apex:inputtext value="{!prt.serial}"  styleClass="jq_req" />
</apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Test class:

```
@isTest(seeAlldata=true)
public class SitePartsUpdateTest{
static testMethod void SitePartsUpdateMethod(){
Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('id',String.valueof(Sales.Id));


 SitePartsUpdate Spu=new SitePartsUpdate();
 Spu.SitePartsUpdate();

List<SitePartsUpdate.SiteParts> PartsList=new List<SitePartsUpdate.SiteParts>();
SitePartsUpdate.SiteParts sp=new SitePartsUpdate.SiteParts('Test','123');
PartsList.add(sp);

 Spu.getParts(); 


Spu.SaveAssest();
Spu.Cancel();
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of using **bold** for method names, consider using `code formatting`, with (```) backticks. It looks much cleaner, and is easier to identify as code. Consider: **Controller.Method(parameter)** against `Controller.Method(parameter)`. You can read more about [markdown in the help section](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: @battery.cord fine I will use that next time I ask questions. what about solution?did you know

Comment: Sankar -- Community is at its greatest assistance when you take the advice from @battery.cord re: code formatting by using the [edit] link.  Your code is not indented at all and many community members will just bypass this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line:

```
PartsList.add(new SiteParts(OLI.Product__r.Name,''));
```

You are creating a new `SiteParts` object by calling it's constructor and the second parameter in your case is just an empty string. Then you say, that you can not cover this if-condition:

```
if(!String.isBlank(SNum.serial)){
```

Let's look into [Apex String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm):

> `isBlank(inputString)`
>
> Returns true if the specified String is white space, empty (''), or null; otherwise, returns false.

So when you make this check, `isBlank()` return `true`, because it's an empty string. The exclamation mark turns this `true` into a `false`. Therefore you will never get into this if-condition

---

I'll also give you some tips for writing test classes:

- Use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` methods
- It might be useful to move the setup part into [another method](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses)
- Make sure to test **EVERY POSSIBLE SCENARIO!** You can and should NOT test everything in one test method(or even worse: get coverage only)

And, probably the most important: **USE ASSERTS WHEN WRITING TEST CLASSES!**
Test classes are called **test** classes because they should actually *test* something and not only provide coverage, otherwise we would call them *coverage classes*. A test class without assert is useless, doesn't test anything and should not even be called a test class.

If, after this, some part of your code is still not covered ask yourself *"Do I even need this code? When is it used?"* and remove it.

Comment: I knew its not covered because of ! condition but in visualforce page its changed dynamically to some value hence if condition works that  I  can't make in  test class .I want to know that how to do that.